# How to create fixed width overwriting array in Redux?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux, concatenation

I have a React button that generates codes and stores them in Redux upon multifile upload, every time you drop a file it adds new code, this is how state looks after 3 uploads:

```
codes: ["a141", "a196", "a953"]
```

I want to store up to 3 codes at once, if user uploads 7 files at once I want to simply shift 4 first codes so the most recent codes are always at the end of an array. I know I could achieve this by mixing of pushing and shifting or concating but how do I achive this in immutable Redux? Should I do this in reducer? Right now I'm accepting everything, like this:

```
case "get_codes":
  return {
    ...state,
    codes: state.codes.concat(action.data.code),
};
```

tl;dr how do I limit number of items in an array in Redux, I've been googling around this topic but couldn't find anything specific :/

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
codes: [...state.codes.concat(action.data.code).slice(-3)]
```

With this you create a new array containing old and new codes and then you take the first 3 in the list.

Comment: but this will always give first three, and whereas the value you're appending is at the end

Comment: True, changed to `unshift` instead of `concat`

Comment: `unshift` mutates original array mate

Comment: True, so let's change to `slice(-3)`

Answer (score 0):

You probably need this

```
codes: state.codes.concat(action.data.code).slice(-3)
```

This will give you the last 3 added elements of array

[`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

You can enhance it a bit

```
codes: action.data.code.length > 3 ? action.code.data.slice(-3) : state.codes.concat(action.data.code).slice(-3)
```